# adding {date: new Date( ) } to { body: 'abc' }

Tags: javascript, json

How to add

`{date: 11 Nov 2013 }`

to

`{ question: { title: 'a', body: 'b' },
  tags: [ { name: 'Civil Laws' } ] }`

so that it looks like :-

```
{ 
 question: { title: 'a', body: 'b' }, 
 tags: [ { name: 'Civil Laws' } ], date: 11 Nov 2013 
}
```

in javascript.

Comment: Just add it? What's the problem?

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried?

Comment: You need to quote the date value, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your

```
{ question: { title: 'a', body: 'b' }, tags: [ { name: 'Civil Laws' } ] }
```

is actually assigned to a variable, like

```
myObject = { question: { title: 'a', body: 'b' }, tags: [ { name: 'Civil Laws' } ] }
```

So just use

```
myObject.date = new Date()
```

or

```
myObject["date"] = new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 13)
```

or

```
myObject.date = "13 Nov 2013"
```

Or any combination of those, depending on what exactly you're after...

If you're asking about how best to serialize dates into JSON, that is a different issue discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format) (and everywhere else when Googling for *JSON dates*)

**Update: after reading dooxe's answer, I realise that you were probably asking about combining two objects into one. In which case [dooxe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19932233/1641835) is probably what you want**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/Sn9zD/1/

Javascript:

```
function extend(o1, o2)
{
   for(var p in o2)
   {
      o1[p] = o2[p];
   }
   return o1;
}
```

Then :

```
var d = {date: new Date() };
var o = { 
 question: { title: 'a', body: 'b' }, 
 tags: [ { name: 'Civil Laws' } ]
};
o = extend(o, d);
```

If you use jQuery, you have jQuery.extend.

Answer (score 0):

The problem becomes simple when u realize `x = { question: { title: 'a', body: 'b' }, tags: [ { name: 'Civil Laws' } ] };` is actually a javascript object.

hence: `x.date = new Date();` would do it